# How to analyze of the complexity of this code?

Tags: algorithm, amortized-analysis

I am solving a [problem](http://codeforces.com/contest/5/problem/E) from codeforces. According to the [editorial](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/213), the complexity of the following code should be O(n).

```
for(int i = n - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    r[i] = i + 1;
    while (r[i] < n && height[i] > height[r[i]])
        r[i] = r[r[i]];
    if (r[i] < n && height[i] == height[r[i]]) 
        r[i] = r[r[i]];
}
```

Here, `height[i]` is the height of `i`-th hill and `r[i]` is the position of the first right hill which is higher than `height[i]`, and `height[0]` is the always greatest among other values of height array.

*My question is, how we can guarantee the complexity of the code to be O(n) although the inner while loop's being?*

In the inner while loop, the code updates `r[i]` values until `height[i]` > `height[r[i]]`. and the number of the updates depends on height array. For example, the number of updates of the height array sorted by non-decreasing order will be different from that of the height array sorted by non-increasing order. (in both cases, the we will sort the array except `height[0]`, because `height[0]` should be always maximum in this problem).

And Is there any method to analyze an algorithm which varies on input data like this? amortized analysis will be one of answers?

PS. I would like to clarify my question more, We are to set the array r[] in the loop. And what about this? if the array `height = {5,4,1,2,3}` and `i=1`, (`r[2]=3`, `r[3]=4` because 2 is the first value which is greater than 1, and 3 is the first value which is greater than 2) we are to compare 4 with 1, and because 4>1, we keep trying to compare 4 and 2(=`height[r[2]]`), 4 with 3(=`height[r[3]]`). In this case we have to compare 4 times to set r[1]. The number of comparison is differ from when `height = {5,1,2,3,4}`. Can we still guarantee the complexity of the code to be O(n)? If I miss something, Please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the mentioned algorithm with simple example, but it seems nothing changed, did I miss something ?

**Example:**

```
n = 5
height = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 }
r = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }

---- i:4 ----

r[4] < 5 ?

---- i:3 ----

8 > 10 ?
8 = 10 ?

---- i:2 ----

6 > 8 ?
6 = 8 ?

---- i:1 ----

4 > 6 ?
4 = 6 ?

---- i:0 ----

2 > 4 ?
2 = 4 ?

-------------

height = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 }
r = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algo (I do not know whether it will solve your problem) is actually O(n), even though there is an inner loop, but in most of the cases inner loop will not execute because of given the conditions. So in worst case it will run like `2n` time, which is O(n).

You can test this assumption with a method like this where `yourMethod` will return the number of time it's inner loop were executed:

```
   int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    do {
        int count = yourMethod(arr, 5);
    }while(next_permutation(arr, arr+5));
```

With this you will be able check the worst case, average case, etc.